# onClickListener in ViewHolder is not called in android pre lollipop

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a `RecyclerView` and I define an OnClickListener to the View of the holder. everything works great on android 5 devices but on 4.4.4 an 4.2.2 for example, the onClickListener is never called.
Here is the relevant code:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved the problem as there was another layer drawn over it according the SDK version. 
Debug GPU overdraw (in the developer options) was very helpful.